# Exact difference between data of rows in two files in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, scripting, diff

Need exact output of difference between two files. Data was in rows separated by comma and there was number of rows, for example I have shown you only one row. Each string should look for every string in other file.

example:

file1.txt

```
abc,def,ghi,klm,nop
one,two,three,four,five,six
```

file2.txt

```
abc,def,ghi,klm,nop
one,two,three,test,four,five,six
```

expected output:

```
test
```

Comment: a quick one `grep -ho '[^,]*' file1.txt file2.txt | sort | uniq -u` but I am not sure if it would work for OP's real input

Comment: What should be the output if the second file contains not `test` but `te,st`?

Comment: ... and what about `"te,st"`? I'm fishing for whether it's needed to do proper CSV file parsing or not.

Answer (score 2):

***Python*** approach with [***difflib***](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) (Helpers for computing deltas) and [***sys***](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) modules:

***differ.py***:

```
import difflib, sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f1, open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as f2:
    differ = difflib.Differ()
    for l in differ.compare(f1.read().split(','), f2.read().split(',')):
        if (l.startswith('+ ') or l.startswith('- ')):
            sys.stdout.write(l[2:] + '\n')
```

*Usage:*

```
python differ.py file1.txt file2.txt
```

The output:

```
test
```

---

`difflib.Differ` - a class for comparing sequences of lines of text, and producing human-readable differences or deltas

Answer (score 0):

The all time classic gnu awk approach:

```
awk -v RS=",|\n" 'NR==FNR{seen[$0]++;next}!seen[$0]' file1 file2 
test
```

This works because we are using also comma as awk line/record separator (RS), and thus we get an output like this for each file:

```
awk -v RS=",|\n" '{print $0}' file1
abc
def
ghi
klm
nop
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

Comment: @Sundeep I lost your point... this awk will work even if last two entries are swapped. What is the bug you found...?

Comment: @Sundeep You were right. Answer updated. Now seems to work ok.

Comment: @sam answer updated